# how to load content div in lightbox in joomla2.5?

Tags: jquery, html, joomla2.5

i created a joomla2.5 template via one page design (section by section). now I want to load the content div in a light box that when i click a article that load in a pop up lightbox. how do i do that? help me! please..

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to search for a jquery lightbox script. I prefer **fancybox** but it needs a license for commercial usage. You can download it from: [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

Then you have to include js files in your template using joomla method.

```
<?php
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

For further help: [Adding JavaScript](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript)

Last step is to prepare the content for lightbox. It could be done by adding `tmpl=component` parameter to the url so content will be loaded without modules / styling.

I would also suggest this article for further reading: [Adding print pop-up functionality to a component](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_print_pop-up_functionality_to_a_component).

Hope this helps.